# Unity rigidbodies movePosition over network

Tags: unity-game-engine

I think this is a network setting problem,

I am having some issues with my game in unity and I have been at it for several days. I am using rigidbody.movePosition to have a object follow a vr controller. If I hold down a button I start to move and I can swing the object with my arm. everything works perfect in regular testing. However, once I tried to use networking the rigidbody freezes once I push the button. when i stop pressing it snaps back to place.

couple notes. my rigidbody is in a seperate empty. kinematic is on. My problem is fixed if i turn off kinematic but the object floats away.

```
private Rigidbody r; 
public SteamVR_TrackedObject controller; 

void Start () {
    r.GetComponent<Rigidbody> (); 
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    r.MovePosition (controller.transform.position);
    r.MoveRotation (controller.transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: maybe some code

Comment: hi yes...I am using armswinger, a locomotion method that you may not  familar with it but I dont want to post the guys code from unity asset store. I just figured that it had to be a problem i am not understanding with the network.

Comment: Ive reposted with the basic code..It works fine pre-networking. my objects follow the controller non stop..One idea is I put the network id on steams entire camera rig instead of the empty game objects and maybe as a move through world space my objects are not getting the information sent...i dont know..i am new to networking aspect of unity

Comment: so obviously position of controller does not represent exactly what you expect. try to debug.log it first. narrow it down, then post something that people actually can help.

Comment: I figured it out. It was so simple. Basically I was placing the objects inside the steam camera rig. Instead i made a new empty with the and placed the camera rig and the object in there together so the global position would not be effected by sending and receiving information. I hope this helps anyone who has a similar problem